# Terraform: Deploying the same web-app for multiple clients

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, consul

I am currently using Terraform to deploy a PHP app to AWS.
This PHP app is deployed as a Service using AWS ECS.

I have multiple clients using this app, and each client receives their own copy of the system with their own configuration as **their own service** - a white label if you will.

Now, having done a bit of research on Terraform I've modularized my code and created the following file structure:

```
+---my-application
    |   shared.tf
    |   iam_policies.tf
    |   iam_roles.tf
    |   variables.tf
    |   web-apps.tf
    |   
    +---modules
    |   \---role
    |   |       main.tf
    |   |       outputs.tf
    |   |       variables.tf
    |   |       
    |   \---webapp
    |           main.tf
    |           variables.tf
    |           
    +---templates
            web_definition.tpl.json
```

My problem lies in the `web-apps.tf` file which I use as the "glue" for all of the `webapp` modules:

```
module "client_bob" {
  source = "modules/webapp"
  ...
}

module "client_alice" {
  source = "modules/webapp"
  ...
}

... Over 30 more client module blocks ...
```

Needless to say that this is not a good setup.
It is not scalable and also creates *huge* `.tfstate` files.

Once when attempting to use Consul as a backend I got an error message saying I've reached the size limit allowed for Consul KV value.

What is the correct way to approach this situations?

I've looked at all of the questions in the *Similar Questions* section when I wrote this one and all of them revolve around the idea of using multiple `.tfstate` files, but I don't quite understand how this would solve my problem, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Only initial thought is that `modules` should be a peer directory to the `my-application` config. Not sure if that fixes your "huge `.tfstate`" problem, but it does help with organization.

Comment: Good suggestion @MattSchuchard thanks, I will make this structural change later on, for now I'm really having a hard time understanding what is the correct way to implement this infrastructure for all of my clients...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did similar projects with `terragrunt`, take a look.
It was born to answer your requests.

the oss website is https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt

> `Terragrunt` is a thin wrapper for Terraform that provides extra tools for working with multiple Terraform modules. https://www.gruntwork.io

In your case, you can easily manage with different tfstate files for each client.

I also recommend to manage the iam roles, policies  or any other resources for each client as well, do not mix them.

For example, the structure will become to

(I guess you will manage different environments for each client, right?)

```
└── bob
    ├── prod
    │   ├── app
    │   │   └── terraform.tfvars
    ├── nonprod
        ├── app
            └── terraform.tfvars
└── alice
    ├── prod
    │   ├── app
    │   │   └── terraform.tfvars
    ├── nonprod
        ├── app
            └── terraform.tfvars

...
```

Later, after you master the command `terraform apply-all`, then it makes the deployment simpler and easier.

#### Quick start

https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt-infrastructure-modules-example

https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt-infrastructure-live-example

Comment: As I see from the resources you posted there are many approaches to solving this issue, with many dedicated developers attempting to do so like [this](https://github.com/elocnatsirt/terrafirm) and [this](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt). Thanks to the resources you posted I started researching some more and learned a lot of information, so I'll accept this answer due to this, thank you.

Comment: There's one more thing I need to understand: Are you supposed to manage these directories (sub-projects) from a root directory, or am I supposed to `cd` into each of them and run `terraform init` ?
If I do the latter, then each nested sub-project for every client has its own `.terraform` folder, is that the right practice?

Comment: with `terragrunt`, you don't need to run `terraform init` at all. Second, if you know how to use `plan-all`, `apply-all`, you needn't cd to each subproject/subclient directories.